# HTTPS shows website correctly, HTTP shows IIS start page

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, http, https

Just setup a new VPS server and am migrating a few clients to it from my dedicated server. The new VPS server is Win Server 2008 with IIS7.

For some reason, when you go to http version using the ip, you get the IIS Start screen. When you go to https version with the ip, you get the website. Why would the https version work and not the http?

I have the following bindings set on the site:

(Type, Host Name, Port)

http www.domainname.com 80

http domainname.com 80

https blank 443

What do I need to check or what setting might be incorrect? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP bindings are specific to requests which include an HTTP `Host:` header specifying the domain (or the domain with www), while your HTTPS binding gets all requests on and address to port 443.

When you send a request using the IP instead of a domain name, the IP is used as the `Host:` header - the default site, instead of your newly configured one, is handling the request.

This behavior is to be expected when you have multiple sites bound to the same IP; if this isn't what you were looking to configure, then you can probably just disable the default site and remove the domain names from your port 80 bindings.

Comment: When I removed the domain name from the Host Name binding, it now works. The reason I was using the IP is because the site is still live on the dedicated box and wanted to make sure it worked before switching the dns. When I change the dns, will I need to add the domain back into the Host Name param? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tony Nope, it will match any request when no name is configured, so no need to have the domain if you don't have multiple sites on the port - just make sure you don't leave the default site enabled if it's bound to all names on port 80 as well.

Comment: I will have other domains on the port, but not on the ip address. So does this mean I need to add the domain back in when I change the dns?